# Calling Go using PHP's shell_exec is changing GOPATH

Tags: php, go

I have a Go app that must run from a PHP script with `shell_exec()`/`exec()`. The problem is when I call the Go script that way, the GOPATH changes or can't be found, and the imports from `go get` can't be found too. Everything is fine when I call it manually on terminal.

Trying to solve it, the GOPATH was set to `/var/www` on .bashrc and updated with `source ~/.bashrc`), but when I use `go env` under apache's user (www-data), the folders act like the Apache user can't read the environment variables and read the default values but the root folder from Go's view is `/var/www`, not `/`.

How can I make apache/PHP run Go properly?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting your env variables in `.bashrc`, use the profile files. I'm not familiar with how PHP calls exec, but you should be familiar with how and where the shell gets it's environment. Read the `INVOCATION` section in the bash man page.

Comment: Change it to ~/.profile is enough? I'm reading it but apply and understand everything necessary to that takes time. Also, that could help me or it's off-topic?

Comment: If you are using shell_exec you can just set GOPATH right there: `shell_exec('GOPATH=/var/www go get ...')`. However, you should really just compile your Go program once (with `go build` or `go install`) and then execute *that* instead of go.

Comment: That's true, completely forgot go is compiled. I'll try it.

Comment: Problem solved. thank you guys. @Peter you want to make an answer?